# Centering an element only when screen is at max width (adding min-width property)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Centering an element only when screen is at max width**

At the moment, I am centering various elements (by JavaScript) by calculating the screen's width and setting the element's "margin-left" to screen.width/2 - element.width/2.

I do this so that when the user resizes the window, the element will stay in the absolute center of the screen and become invisible if the window is resized to less than 50%.

Is this a typical way to center things only at the max width, or is there a simpler CSS approach to achieving the same effect?

An example of the effect I am trying to achieve: Khanacademy.com's logo.

[Edit]
Thanks to hungerstar, I was able to figure out the root cause of my issue. If you do not set a min-width, then margin: 0 auto will always keep your element centered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/114543/139010

Comment: Post WHAT you are trying to center.  Your question includes no substance to work with.

Comment: That logo is always centered.

Comment: That's because of the width of the site.  There's a scroll bar at the bottom.  It's still centered in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a group of elements that need to be centered but need to maintain left alignment or other formatting, i.e. a heading followed by paragraphs with lists, you can do the following:

*HTML*

```html
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="outer">
         <div class="inner">... Content...</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
#wrapper {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 900px;
}
.outer {
     height: 50px;
     left: 50%;
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block; /* or float: left; */
}
.inner {
     right: 50%;
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me either. When I resize my window, the element remains centered, which is not the desired result.

Comment: Do you have a max width for the site?  If so then use CSS3 media queries.  You question is a little vague on the desired result.  I would re-state what your objective is.

Comment: I am trying to center a logo ONLY when the browser is at maximum width. So basically, I want the window to be a frame and I do not want the logo to "re-center" itself upon resizing the window.

Comment: See updated answer.  That Kahn Academy logo is using a modified version of what I've posted.

Comment: I thought I already had my max width set. That was my issue. Thank you!

Comment: For reference, if others end up on this post, it is better to use a min-width than a fixed width.

Answer (score 2):

For block elements, giving an explicit width plus `margin: 0 auto` is the basic technique. Inline (and inline-block) elements such as images you can center using `text-align:center` on the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using css.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FSP9K/1/)

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I resize the window, the element remains centered, which is not what I want.